# How to create objects with values in an other object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to create an object that contains lets say 3 other object in it and each of those 3 have 2 values.

This is the **result** I'm looking for:

> { 0: {x:1, y:3}, 1: {x:4, y:2}, 2: {x:5, y:0} }

**My code:**

```
let obj = {};
let oneToTen = Array.from(Array(2).keys());

obj[oneToTen] = {
    x: randomeNumber,
    y: randomeNumber
};
```

I can't figure out how to push random numbers in x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `for loop`, you can use the counter value as the Object key (which is **automatically casted to a string**), and in each loop iteration generate and assign the child object.

This code will generate 3 child objects, containing each one `x` and `y` with random values (in the range 0-10).

```js
let obj={};
let maxChildren = 3; 

for(let i=0; i<maxChildren; i++){
  obj[ i ]={
    x: Math.floor(Math.random()*11),
    y: Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
  }
}


console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your using `Array.from` you could just make your objects there, then destructure the array as on object, which will give you the indexes as keys:

```js
let oneToTen = Array.from({length: 3}, () => {
  return {
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random()
  }
});

let obj = { ...oneToTen}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  obj[oneToTen]
```

Is the same as

```
 obj[[0, 1, 2]]
```

which will then evaluate to:

```
 obj["0,1,2"]
```

So you actually set one property. You want to use a loop:

```
 for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   obj[i] = { /*...*/ };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try Something like this

```js
    const oneToTen = Array.from(Array(2).keys());
    const obj = oneToTen.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] = {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    }
    return acc; 
    }, {});
    console.log(obj);
```